# Apache Hive - Programmetically same query but different result, why?

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-emr

#### **Concern 01.**

I have 2 tables Table1 has 41 columns and more than 100mil records and Table2 has 20 columns and 10mil records.

I was using the following queries to verify the records.

Query 01.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (
  t1.c_id = t2.c_id AND
  t1.e_id = t2.e_id AND
  t1.o_id = t2.o_id
)
```

Query 02.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (
  t1.c_id = t2.c_id AND
  t1.e_id = t2.e_id AND
  t1.o_id = t2.o_id
) GROUP BY t2.c_id
```

The issue is, Query 01 count and Query 02 (sum) do not match. Could someone please point out the issue here?

#### **Concern 02.**

In addition to above 2 tables there is another table(client) contain only the c_ids.

Query 03.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (
  t1.c_id = t2.c_id AND
  t1.e_id = t2.e_id AND
  t1.o_id = t2.o_id
) WHERE t2.c_id IN ("client_id1", "client_id1", ...);
```

Query 04.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON (
  t1.c_id = t2.c_id AND
  t1.e_id = t2.e_id AND
  t1.o_id = t2.o_id
) WHERE t2.c_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c_id FROM client);
```

In Query 03, I'm hard-coding the c_ids and in Query 04 I'm asking the Hive to get the IDs from the client table. If we assume in both cases c_ids are the same, do you think there could be any count difference in queries?

Because I noticed when I hard-coded the c_ids in Query 03 result count was lower than in Query 04. Please let me know if I made a mistake in these queries or if there could be a data issue.

also if I need to get the same answer for both queries what changes that I need to make for the queries?

They are running on AWS EMR Hive 3.1.3-amzn-0 version

Answer (score 1):

The difference in counts between Query 01 and Query 02 is likely due to the way you're grouping the results in Query 02. In Query 01, you're simply counting the total number of matching records between the two tables, while in Query 02, you're grouping by t2.c_id and then counting the records within each group.

This means that if there are multiple records in table2 with the same t2.c_id that match with a single record in table1, Query 02 will count them as one match for that t2.c_id, whereas Query 01 counts each individual match.

##### Concern 2

To ensure that you get the same count for both queries, you need to make sure that the list of `c_ids` is the same and that there are no duplicates in the client table. Also, ensure that there are no data quality issues affecting the results. If necessary, you may want to validate the contents of the client table to confirm that it matches your expectations.

Comment: Thanks, Leeroy for your explanation. I might need a minute to think about it. In the meantime, can you check the Concern 02 aswell I have update the question since both kind of similar questions. TIA.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your update.